# Detect a newline character

Tags: php

the following is part of myfunction which opens a file and places the pointer at the end. It then tests each character `$char` in reverse order until it finds a newline or a carriage return character.

The problem is it is not recognising these characters.

The function is as follows:

```
while(count($results) < $limit && fseek($this->_pointer, $offset, SEEK_END) >= 0) {
    $char = fgetc($this->_pointer);
    if($char == '\n' || $char == '\r'){
        print("YAY");
        $offset --;
        $data = $this->explodeData(fgets($this->_pointer, 1024));
        array_push($results, $this->formatRow($data));
    }
    $offset--;
}
```

It never manages to `print("YAY")` however it is successfully testing each character. The file it is reading definitely has newlines in it.
(The file was created by another function and has had `"\n"` inserted in it, this is showing inside it and is showing in my IDE successfully as being on alternate lines).

Does anyone know why it is unable to recognise these newline characters?

Comment: This procedure seems overkill a bit... What is the goal of this procedure? If you want to extract one of the few last lines, you'd be better off using "file()" and getting the last few entries in the array.

Comment: Is "\n" considered a character or two characters? It's put together by two characters ( '\' and 'n' ), so wouldn't your script fail if you only check one character at a time?

Comment: @RunarJørgensen `"\n"` is converted to a newline character

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin This is faster than reading the whole file into the memory and converting it into an array and then retrieving the data. This literally just reads the line(s) it needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using `'\n'` instead of `"\n"`.

```
while(count($results) < $limit && fseek($this->_pointer, $offset, SEEK_END) >= 0) {
    $char = fgetc($this->_pointer);
    if($char == "\n" || $char == "\r"){
        print("YAY");
        $offset --;
        $data = $this->explodeData(fgets($this->_pointer, 1024));
        array_push($results, $this->formatRow($data));
    }
    $offset--;
}

"\n" == LF character
'\n' == '\n';

// Variables are effected also
$var = 'foo';

print "$var"; // prints 'foo';
print '$var'; // prints '$var';
```

Comment: Duh, thanks :). I stupidly forgot this earlier and replaced all `"` with `'` with a find and replace to be consistent. I bet there's loads of occurences.

Answer (score 17):

To make your code platform agnostic it is better to have your if condition like this:

```
if($char == PHP_EOL) {
   print("YAY");
   // your rest of the code
}
```

---

Thanks to @Félix Gagnon-Grenier comment below.

`PHP_EOL` might not work on strings that come from other systems. `PHP_EOL` represents the endline character for the current system.

To make it detect all kind of newline characters including unicode newlines use `\R`:

```
preg_match('/\R/', $str);
```

`\R` is equivalent of `(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85|\x{2028}|\x{2029})`

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/959055)

Comment: Careful: while this is indeed useful, it might not work on strings that come from other systems. PHP_EOL represents the endline character for the current system (eg \n on unixes) however if you are treating strings from a windoes system (\r\n) they won't be rexognised as endlines. PHP_EOL is "[The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)". By the way, this will indeed not return true for all three of those line endings, you can see [here](https://eval.in/959046).

Answer (score 4):

use double quotes instead of single quotes around the "\n" and "\r"

i had a similiar nightmare a while back, until i realized that php does not use escape characters unless they're in double quotes.